# groovy is calling getProperty in superclass in weird case?

Tags: groovy

I have an abstract class extending the groovy Script class with a getProperty method that is called when loading variables.  I did not expect it to be called for the package 'org' in this line of groovy

```
_attrs3 = [items:org.webpieces.plugins.hibernate.app.dbo.LevelOfEducation.values(), as:'level']; //htmlLine 19:19  groovyLine=66
```

I put a breakpoint and I see groovy is trying to load 'org'.  is there any way to escape this action?  as I want to skip a safety check that I have in the getProperty method.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Do you have a minimal example showing the issue?

Comment: I found this class is not on the classpath so does groovy then treat it as a property?  I think maybe that is why